# Визуальный онлайн редактор кода

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, редактор

Здравствуйте. Хочу создать простой онлайн редактор кода (JQuery + PHP). Подскажите пожалуйста с чего мне начать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы не использовать уже готовые решения вроде [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/) и [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)?

Comment: Разрабатываю проект, для которого нужен собственный редактор. Да и опыт дополнительный получить хочу.

Comment: С изучения кода других онлайн-редакторов кода - раз, с библиотек подсветки синтаксиса - два.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с написания ТЗ. Кратко обрисуйте, какой функционал вы хотите видеть в Вашем редакторе, разбейте этот функционал на три группы, условно: 1. Must have, 2. Желательно, и 3. То, что будет делаться в последнюю очередь если не будет лень (хи-хи). Затем для каждой группы составьте подзадачи, с как можно более подробным описанием алгоритма работы и процесса разработки. По идее, к этому моменту уже должно появиться понимание того, что вы знаете, а чего не знаете. И вот когда это понимание у Вас появится, начинайте гуглить предметно по пробелам в знаниях. Вот, в общем-то, и всё. А так,  с нуля.. с чего начать? С начала :)

P.S. На самом раннем этапе, когда будете обдумывать функционал нового редактора, нелишним будет задаться двумя вопросами: 1. Чем он будет отличаться от других редакторов, и 2. Нет ли готового редактора, который уже воплощает Ваши желания и стремления. Отсюда сам по себе вытечет третий вопрос - стоит ли овчинка выделки? Опыт - дело, конечно, хорошее, вот только получать его лучше на реальных проектах, а не на изобретении велосипедов. Ибо чужие велосипеды всё равно будет и легче, и изящнее, так и разочароваться в профессии недолго. Надеюсь, не задел. Удачи.